# How to clear form fields in class-based views after a submit in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, reset-password

I use **class-based views for password reset** in my Django project. My form has only one field where users can write there email adress or username. After successfull submit users can see success message in the same page. My problem is that after the submit I see empty field but in the same time I can send data again by clicking button. **How to clear form field after the successfull submit?** I am little bit comfusing.

**views.py**

```
class PasswordResetRequestView(FormView):
    template_name = "registration/password_reset.html"
    success_url = '/account/password_reset'
    form_class = PasswordResetRequestForm

    @staticmethod
    def validate_email_address(email):
        try:
            validate_email(email)
            return True
        except ValidationError:
            return False

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        global data
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        try:
            if form.is_valid():
                data = form.cleaned_data["email_or_username"]
            if self.validate_email_address(data) is True:
                associated_users = User.objects.filter(Q(email=data) | Q(username=data))
                if associated_users.exists():
                    for user in associated_users:
                        c = {
                            'email': user.email,
                            'domain': request.META['HTTP_HOST'],
                            'site_name': 'your site',
                            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                            'user': user,
                            'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
                            'protocol': 'http',
                        }
                        subject_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_subject.txt'
                        email_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_email.html'
                        subject = loader.render_to_string(subject_template_name, c)
                        subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())
                        email = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, c)
                        send_mail(subject, email, DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [user.email], fail_silently=False)
                    result = self.form_valid(form)
                    messages.success(request, 'An email has been sent to ' +
                                     data + ". Please check its inbox to continue reseting password.")
                    return result
                result = self.form_invalid(form)
                messages.error(request, 'No user is associated with this email address')
                return result
            else:
                associated_users = User.objects.filter(username=data)
                if associated_users.exists():
                    for user in associated_users:
                        c = {
                            'email': user.email,
                            'domain': 'example.info',
                            'site_name': 'example',
                            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                            'user': user,
                            'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
                            'protocol': 'http',
                        }
                        subject_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_subject.txt'
                        email_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_email.html'
                        subject = loader.render_to_string(subject_template_name, c)
                        # Email subject *must not* contain newlines
                        subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())
                        email = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, c)
                        send_mail(subject, email, DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [user.email], fail_silently=False)
                    result = self.form_valid(form)
                    messages.success(request, 'Email has been sent to ' +
                                     data + "'s email address. Please check its inbox to continue reseting password.")
                    return result
                result = self.form_invalid(form)
                messages.error(request, _('This username does not exist in the system.'))
                return result
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: are you saying that submitting a blank form does not raise an error?

Comment: and/or are you saying that on success you want to redirect them to another page?

Comment: @luke_aus There is no error and I dont want to redirect. Success message I see in the same page. Just after succesfull submit you can send data again and again however there is no data in fields (empty field). Thats not good. For thats why I want to clean form field after succesfull submit. I think I need to initialize form `form = self.form_class(request.POST)` somewhere again but little bit comfused. What do you think?

Comment: You must redirect after a POST. You can redirect back to the same page if you want to, but you must redirect. And **you must absolutely not ever ever use global variables**, especially not to keep your form data in!

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for your answer. As you said problem was in global value. It  works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

First, never ever use global variables.

Second, you can put your post logic into a `form.save()` method. IMO its is much more appropriate there and its close to what `Django` is doing inside its [PasswordResetForm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L228)

This is how your `Form` class can look like:

```
class PasswordResetRequestForm(forms.Form):
    #We are not using EmailField on purpose
    #because you want to treat it
    #as a username if its not an email
    email = forms.CharField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #For sending emails we are gonna need the request.
        request = kwargs.pop('request')
        super(PasswordResetRequestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_email(self):
        #You can add form error here if no user exists
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        users = User.objects.filter(Q(email=email)|Q(username=email))
        if not users.exists():
            self.add_error('email', 'No associated account found')

    def send_email(self, user):
        c = {
            'email': user.email,
            'domain': self.request.META['HTTP_HOST'],
            'site_name': 'your site',
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            'user': user,
            'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
            'protocol': 'http',
        }
        subject_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_subject.txt'
        email_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_email.html'
        subject = loader.render_to_string(subject_template_name, c)
        subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())
        email = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, c)
        send_mail(subject, email, DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [user.email], fail_silently=False)

    def save(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        users = User.objects.filter(Q(email=email)|Q(username=email))

        for user in users:
            self.send_email(user)

        messages.success(self.request, """An email has been sent to %s. 
            Please check its inbox to continue reseting password.""" % email
        )
```

And now in the `View` you just need to send the `request` as a `form.kwarg` and call the `form.save()` when the `form.is_valid().

```
class PasswordResetRequestView(FormView):
    template_name = "registration/password_reset.html"
    success_url = '/account/password_reset'
    form_class = PasswordResetRequestForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(PasswordResetRequestView, self).get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = kwargs['form']
        form.save()
        return super(PasswordResetRequestView, self).form_valid(*args, **kwargs)
```